# Dynamically capturing Remote validation property name/value

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a working Remote validation for an MVC web app and want to expand it slightly and wondering if this is possible.

Currently have this validation line in my model

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Forename")]
    [Remote("doesUserNameExist", "Treeview", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Already exists")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
```

My understanding is Remote Validation will send the user input as Form Data which will have the same name as property. So, in this case it is Forename

The controller class will need a Forename variable to pick this up such as:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult doesUserNameExist(string Forename)
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> user = new List<SelectListItem>();
        using (EIPInternalEntities ctx = new EIPInternalEntities())
        {
            user = new SelectList(ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>("EXEC dbo.uspGetLkUpJobTitle").ToList());
        }         

        return Json(!user.Any(x => x.Text.ToUpper() == Forename.ToUpper()));
    }
```

What I would like however, is to have a class where I can dynamically set a variable to be the value without know the property name that is being sent in as well as then evaluate and capture the property name.

The property name I would then pass into the stored procedure which would query a view to return the correct column, and the dynamic value would be compared against that.

This would then prevent the need of replicating this code for each instance of a Remote check needed in the application.

So, is there a way to dynamically capture the value?

some sort of

```
var PropName = Metadata.ContainerType.GetProperty(this.Metadata.PropertyName);
```

sorry if that is a bit jibberish, very new to this.